# can C# generic parameters be cast?

Tags: c#, casting

I've written a method with the signature:

```
private List<ClientItem> ConvertToClientItems(BaseCollection<object> serverItems)
```

I'm trying to call it in the following manner:

```
ConvertToClientItems(approvedSellers);
```

where `approvedSellers` is of type `BaseCollection<Seller>` - with `Seller` being a class that I don't have control over.

Shouldn't this be possible? Visual Studio is throwing an error at me saying that it cannot cast `BaseCollection<seller>` to `BaseCollection<object>`.

Comment: That's called covariance.  It's unsafe for mutable collections

Comment: You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but does that mean I can only use the IEnumerable type for covariance?

Comment: What version of .NET are you compiling against? I believe you need to be using .NET 4.0 at least to use covariance

Comment: 4.0, tmk. @BartoszKP it looks to me as if my code should work. The BaseCollection class' parent implements IEnumerable, and changing the signature to IEnumerable didn't fix it.

Comment: Look into using something like Automapper.  Once it is set up, it's as simple as that line of code you're using.  `var obj = Mapper.Map(Of ClientItem)(approvedSellers);`  "Set Up" means creating explicit mappings from each type to the ClientItem type.

Comment: Is there a reason the argument must be of type BaseCollection<object>? If you want it to work for any type, without dealing with covariance, you could make the function generic, such as: `private List<ClientItem> ConvertToClientItems<T>(BaseCollection<T> serverItems)`.

Comment: Also, if covariance is throwing you, think of it this way. It is true that BaseCollection<Seller> contains items that are instances of Object (everything derives from Object). But it isn't type safe to convert BaseCollection<Sellers> into BaseCollection<Object> since, for example, you should not be allowed to add a string to a BaseCollection<Sellers> but you can add it to a BaseCollection<Object>. If the compiler allowed this cast, there would be no point in typed containers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, imagine code that looks like this:

```
private List<ClientItem> ConvertToClientItems(BaseCollection<object> serverItems) {
    serverItems.Add(new Buyer());
}
```

This should compile, since a `Buyer` is an `object`.

However, if you pass a `BaseCollection<Seller>`, you just tried to add a buyer to a list of sellers.

Thus, the statement

*`BaseCollection<Seller>` is a subtype of `BaseCollection<object>`*

only holds if `BaseCollection` ensures that the generic type `T` is only used in **output** positions. The *Add* example above would use `T` in an **input** position.

---

To solve this, you have the following options:

- Make BaseCollection "covariant" by adding the [**out** keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx), which would require removing any `Add` methods. This, however, might make your collection kind of useless.
- Pass a covariant **interface** to the method. If you only need to *read* `serverItems`, pass an `IEnumerable`, which is already covariant (and you mention in the comments that BaseCollection already implements `IEnumerable`):

  ```
  private List<ClientItem> ConvertToClientItems(IEnumerable<object> serverItems) {
      // You can only read serverItems here, so we are fine.
  }
  ```
- make the method itself generic

  ```
  private List<ClientItem> ConvertToClientItems<T>(BaseCollection<T> serverItems) {
      // This also prevents the evil `Add` call, since you'd need to create
      // an object of the correct type T first.
  }
  ```

Comment: I ended up making the method generic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In BaseCollection, you have to make T covariant by using the "out" keyword.

More information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx.

(IEnumerable works because it is covariant.)

```
public interface BaseCollection<out T>
```

Comment: This might have worked, but BaseCollection is nested deep inside a nasty codebase that I inherited, and I was hesitant to change it.